# R - reversing scale of the sec. y axis

Tags: r

I have currently encountered a problem with a R visualization which I just can't get on with. 
The problem is the following, in my data set I have three variables, on the one hand the turnover on the y axis and on the other hand the years on the x axis. Furthermore I would like to show the table placement of the club with a graph. For this the y axis on the right side should not be scaled rising from 0 to 18 but falling from 18 to 1. While my first y axis is scaled rising. So the question is how can I have two y axes with different scaling?

In the following my code:

```
ggplot(na.omit(R_Projekt), aes(x=Jahr,y=Umsatz))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.3), aes(fill=Umsatz)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="dark green",high="#7db83a") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,198), sec.axis = sec_axis(~(198-.)/11,breaks = seq(1,18), name = "Tabellenplatz"))+

  geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=Tabelle*11), colour="#292929",size=1.5) +


  labs(title="Balkendiagramm",x="Jahr", y="Umsatz in Millionen ")+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Can anyone help me? 
Many thanks in advance 
Natalie

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding custom labels for your y-axis: add the following to your scale_y_continuous line:

```
labels = rev(seq(1,18))
```

So:

```
 ggplot(na.omit(R_Projekt), aes(x=Jahr,y=Umsatz))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.3), aes(fill=Umsatz)) +
      scale_fill_gradient(low="dark green",high="#7db83a") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,198), sec.axis = sec_axis(~(198-.)/11,breaks = seq(1,18), labels = rev(seq(1,18)), name = "Tabellenplatz"))+

      geom_line(stat="identity",aes(y=Tabelle*11), colour="#292929",size=1.5) +


  labs(title="Balkendiagramm",x="Jahr", y="Umsatz in Millionen ")+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Greatly appreciate your help! I've been sitting on this problem for almost three days and just haven't found a solution and you just solved it in 7 minutes. Thank you so much!!!